# Can anybody recommend a Bar Code web server control?

Tags: asp.net, barcode, web-controls

Can anybody recommend a Bar Code web server control for formats 39 and 128 formats?

UPDATE: I posted this after being given a choice of 3 controls we'd never heard of.  I was hoping to get a recommendation from somebody who is using something that is popular, stable and a commercial product.  It looks like we will just go with one of the choices our manager sent.  If you are reading this after the fact, and have a good recommendation, please add it for others needing one in the future.  thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a series of articles on CodeProject articles that do just that:

- [Drawing Barcodes in Windows Part 1 - Code 39](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/barcode1.aspx)
- [Drawing Barcodes in Windows Part 5 - Code 128](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/barcode5.aspx)

Another one:

- [Barcode Image Generation Library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/barcode1.aspx)

Another way, using barcode Fonts, but simple to use in ASP.Net

- [Barcodes in ASP.NET applications](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspBarCodes.aspx)

Actually, implementing you own barcode drawing routines is not too hard if you stick with simple 1D barcodes.
The best book ever on the subject is [The Bar Code Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1425133746).  It's one of these absolute reference books that you just want to keep and read out of pure nerdy pleasure.

Comment: Even though this didn't recommend a control as wished for.  It does give a good, short, & detailed explaination of how you can roll your own.  That's why I chose it as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is also an open source ASP.NET barcode generation framework on www.codeplex.com:

http://www.codeplex.com/BarcodeRender

I did have a problem with the Interleaved 2 of 5 symbology, but I believe it was added rather recently. Perhaps the other symbologies are more stable.

Answer (score 0):

Guys... don't go too far. There are Windows Fonts (TrueType fonts / TTF) that can easily be used to draw bar codes. the Graphics object is your friend.

Comment: Many bar code symbologies can't be represented by a simple font. Maybe code 3 or 9 (aka code 39) but not much else. All kinds of check digits and encoding in many.

Comment: Ok, Andrew Robinson, I understand but still I've seen simple tasks elegantly completed using fonts.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, but it's a webapp.  Even though it's an internal app, we still don't want client side dependencies.

Comment: No, John, it does **NOT** require client side dependencies at all. The GDI Graphics object would run on the server in a Generic handler and generate the barcode.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should check out these two options:

1) [www.idautomation.com](http://www.idautomation.com)

2) [barbeque](http://barbecue.sourceforge.net/) open source library (Java) to generate barcodes.

Both are excellent!